# How to show the actual code for html entity or html special character code

Tags: html, htmlspecialchars

I want to show the actual code for the html entity on the screen rather than the interpreted character it represents.  Like on this page: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp or another page that describes the html codes.

I want to show & # 3 8 ; (but without spaces between characters) in the webpage rather than the '&'.

Answer (score 1):

Simply escape the ampersand.

```
&amp;#38;
```

will display as, literally `&#38;` when rendered in HTML.

Comment: so, &amp;amp;#38; would be &amp;amp;amp;#38; ? What?!?! The comments are different encoding?! because the html code shows instead of the entity in the comment section....

Comment: May I ask, is there a PHP function to do this?  Or a existing function?

Answer (score 1):

Try following

I will display &euro;

I will display &#8364;

I will display &#x20AC;

[image]

This may help